# Android ICS MTP can sync only *.mpg format video files?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, mtp

Tried to Sync video files to Galaxy Nexus via MTP, only *mpg format video can be synced and all other formats video files sync got error (C00D123E). That error code indicated that the device doesn't support the video format.

Is this a known issue?

Thanks

Xin